# How to display different strings repeatedly in one UI Text filed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game where the there are 3 strings and one of them will be displayed in the Text UI on the screen, but before displaying it, I want all the three strings to repeat quickly after each other in one text UI (To make it obvious that the text is randomized). So I believe a loop is required here, but it didn't work.

Here is what I tried.

```
    string[] arr = new string[3];
     
    void Start()
    {
        arr[0] = "option1";
        arr[1] = "option2";
        arr[2] = "option3"; 
    }
   foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        buttonText.SetText(s); 
    }
```

please help, how can I display all strings repeatedly after each other fast in the single UI Text?

Comment: Have you used a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to achieve this?

Comment: no, where exactly and how can I use it?

Comment: Please take a look at the example [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: it worked, thank you so much. please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base approach is in the right direction but is missing the Coroutine.

A coroutine allows you to spread tasks across several frames. In Unity, a coroutine is a method that can pause execution and return control to Unity but then continue where it left off on the following frame.

You just had to make minor changes as follows:

```
private IEnumerator Foo()
{
   var wait = new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
   foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        buttonText.SetText(s);
        yield return wait;
    }
}
```

There are different types of wait based on Time(Unity's Time. This is affected by timescale), frame, and read-time(This is not affected by timescale). And you can also use another coroutine as `yield return` to chain the coroutines.

Reference: [Unity-Manual: Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)